# User Interaction Enabled With CAAnimation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-animation

It is very easy to allow users to interact with views while animating using the options field of block based animation. But in my program I am using a CAKeyframeAnimation and I don't see any properties to set user interaction enabled. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks,

EDIT: Here is the actual code:

```
- (void)move
{
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 50, 120);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, arc4random() % 320, arc4random() % 480);
    CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    [animation setPath:path];
    [animation setDuration:10];
    CFRelease(path);
    [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"move"];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self setAlpha:0];
}
```

Comment: Its a property of the view. You should be able to set it in the mainView.

Comment: Legolas, I tried that to no avail. Thanks though

Comment: could you elaborate on what exactly you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want a small square to appear on the screen. Then using keyframe animations have it move around on the screen. I want the user to be able to touch it and then it will disappear. I'll post my code in the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely touching the wrong place. When the layer animates on screen the value never changes so the view is actually positioned where it was from the beginning, not where it appears on screen.

I did a blog post a few month ago on [how to hit test animating layers](http://ronnqvi.st/hit-testing-animating-layers/). It describes the exact thing that you are trying to do.

You will need to add the touch handling (or gesture recognizer) to the superview and do the hit-testing of the `presentationLayer` yourself to determine if the user tapped where the view appeared on screen.

Comment: Thanks David, your article seems to hit exactly the point that I am wondering about. However, I do not want to use a Gesture Recognizer as I want the result directly on the touch down. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yeah, i agree with David's comment. You are actually not playing with the right coordinates. Why dont you trying displaying the coordinates of  where you are touching, and where the cube is, and you can understand a great deal about it.

Comment: David, I just realized you implement the gesture recognizer in the vc. That should work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, preview solution no longer works in Swift 3.x and Swift 4.x

I solved the issue setting a Timer to update the frame during the animation.

```
//Timer: To update the UI frame
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.15, target: self, selector: #selector(updateFrame), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

//Timer Selector
@objc func updateFrame(){
   //getting the layer presentation bounds
    let layer = "button, label...".layer.presentation()!

    let point = CGPoint(x: layer.frame.origin.x, y: layer.frame.origin.y)
    let size = CGSize(width: layer.frame.width, height: layer.frame.height)
    // Update the UI element frame location
    "ui element".frame = CGRect(origin: point, size: size)
}
```