# CABasicAnimation on UIView, Child button is not clickable

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

1. I have view which is rotating like this :

   ```
   if view.layer.animation(forKey: kRotationAnimationKey) == nil {
       let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
       rotationAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
       rotationAnimation.toValue = Float(M_PI * 2.0)
       rotationAnimation.duration = duration
       rotationAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity

       view.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: kRotationAnimationKey)
   }
   ```
2. there are multiple small button on this view.
3. While parent view is rotating and trying to tap on buttons , i am unable to tap and corresponding action method is not getting called.

Please help on this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User Interaction Enabled With CAAnimation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110485/user-interaction-enabled-with-caanimation)

Comment: link given in that post is not working. any help?

Comment: The working link is here: http://ronnqvi.st/hit-testing-animating-layers/. In the future please try googling around first before asking, it was the first hit when googling the title.

Answer (score 0):

When you animate a view or layer, the actual view does not move through the intermediate locations of the animation. Instead, the view object jumps to it's final location at the beginning of the animation. (The animation actually takes place on a "presentation layer" which is laid on top of the view's normal layer hierarchy.)

If you want to be able to tap on a button that's "in flight" in an animation you will have to do hit testing on the view's presentation layer, and you can't have a button respond to touches using target/action.

I have a sample project on Github that demonstrates detecting taps on an in-flight view if you're interested. Take a look at https://github.com/DuncanMC/iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo on Github. It's written in Objective-C, but the idea is the same

Comment: Hi Duncan, Please provide sample project as i tried fixing my code, but it not working.